# Java JSON recovers only one item

Tags: java, json, swing

In a desktop software, the user is available to presh a button and refresh the "database".

All the info is provided by an online service which returns JSON responses, those responses are saved into *DAT* files and then parsed with http://www.json.org/java/index.html in order to be saved into in-memory variables as String. The *DAT* files are only for break-exception-support.

Ok, so I'd created a SwingWorker class which should:

1. parse the content from the in-memory variable
2. iterate through elements
3. recover items
4. update a progress bar

This is an example of the JSON code:

```
{
  "key":"value",
  "data":{
    "Name1":{...},
    "Name2":{...},
    [...]
  }
}
```

The full iteration of the "data" element will create a List, which I must use to create a JTable and populate the main frame of the GUI. But when executing the SwingWorker, it only returns a List which all elements are the last item of the JSON.

Here's the code the SwingWorker:

```
package com.wolfchamane.lolapi;

import com.wolfchamane.logging.LoCLogger;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoLChampions extends SwingWorker{

    private static List<LoLChampion> _list;
    private static JProgressBar _status;
    private static LoCLogger _log;
    private static String _exePath;
    private static String _version;
    private static LoLDDBB _ddbb;
    //private static int _max;

    public List<LoLChampion> getDataTable(){
        return _list;
    }

    public LoLChampions(){}
    public LoLChampions(JProgressBar status){
        this();
        _status = status;
    }
    public LoLChampions(JProgressBar status, LoCLogger log){
        this(status);
        _log = log;
    }
    public LoLChampions(JProgressBar status, LoCLogger log, String path){
        this(status, log);
        _exePath = path;
    }
    public LoLChampions(JProgressBar status, LoCLogger log, String path, LoLDDBB ddbb){
        this(status, log, path);
        _ddbb = ddbb;
    }
    public LoLChampions(JProgressBar status, LoCLogger log, String path, LoLDDBB ddbb, String version) throws Exception{
        this(status, log, path, ddbb);
        _version = version;
    }


    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        getChampionsInfo(_ddbb.getJSONChampions());        
        return true;
    }

    public void getChampionsInfo(JSONObject jsonChampions) throws Exception{

        String fldrImgsPath = _exePath+File.separator+"images";
        String fldrImgsChampions = fldrImgsPath+File.separator+"champions";

        File fldrImages = new File(fldrImgsPath);
        if (fldrImages.isDirectory() || fldrImages.mkdir()){

            File fldrChampions = new File(fldrImgsChampions);
            if (fldrChampions.isDirectory() || fldrChampions.mkdir()){

                JSONObject data = jsonChampions.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray championsNames = data.names();

                int _max = championsNames.length();
                _status.setMaximum(_max);

                if (_list == null)
                    _list = new ArrayList<LoLChampion>();

                int curr = _list.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < _max; i++){
                    _status.setString("Fetching ["+(curr+1)+"/"+_max+"] champions icos");

                    //Champion object
                    LoLChampion champion = new LoLChampion();

                    //Champion name
                    String name = String.valueOf(championsNames.get(i));
                    champion.setChampionName(name);
                    //Champion data
                    JSONObject jsonChamp = data.getJSONObject(name);

                    //Champion roles
                    JSONArray tags = jsonChamp.getJSONArray("tags");
                    //Main role
                    String mRole = String.valueOf(tags.get(0));
                    champion.setChampionMainRole(mRole);
                    //Secondary role (if exists)
                    String sRole = "";                    
                    if (tags.length() > 1)
                        sRole = String.valueOf(tags.get(1));
                    champion.setChampionSecondRole(sRole);

                    //Champion ico.
                    File pf = new File(fldrChampions.getPath()+File.separator+name+".jpg");
                    saveChampionImage(name, pf);                                
                    champion.setChampionIco(pf);

                    //Push LoLChampion object to list
                    _list.add(champion);

                    //Update status bar
                    curr = _list.size();
                    _status.setValue(curr);

                    System.gc();
                }//for:i

                _ddbb.setChampionsList(_list);

            }else{
                _log.error("Couldn't access or create \""+fldrImgsChampions+"\" folder");
                throw new Exception("Couldn't access or create \""+fldrImgsChampions+"\" folder");
            }//fi
        }else{
            _log.error("Couldn't access or create \""+fldrImgsPath+"\" folder");
            throw new Exception("Couldn't access or create \""+fldrImgsPath+"\" folder");
        }//fi

    }

    private void saveChampionImage(String name, File pf) throws Exception{

        String endPointURL = (new ApiURLs()).getChampionsIcoURL();
        endPointURL = endPointURL.replace("{version}", _version);
        endPointURL = endPointURL.replace("{champion}", name);

        try{

            if (!pf.canWrite())
                pf.createNewFile();

            URL url = new URL(endPointURL);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pf);

            _log.info("Getting \""+endPointURL+"\"");
            _log.info("Saving to \""+pf.getPath()+"\"");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int length;
            while((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1){
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }//while

            is.close();
            os.close();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            _log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the complete JSON I want to parse:
https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion?champData=tags&api_key=d34be821-7f22-4d55-85da-7409413e6379

Comment: Indeed, the sample I've provided was wrong typed. My mistake. Now it looks as it really is.

Comment: I think you should provide valid JSON even if you want to obfuscate some values, at least it should be valid as it stands its not helpful

Comment: I think you meant `"data":[{"Name1":{...}},{"Name2":{...}}]`

Comment: No, JSON contains the following: `[...]"data":{"Aatrox":{[..]},"Thresh":{[..]},"Trynd[...]`

Comment: I want to help but I dont know why you dont want to share a real JSON

Comment: I've added the URL where I get the JSON. I could not copy it because of text length limits.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think your JSON example is well formed.  JSON consists of name value pairs. There should be a ":" in between the name and a value.

Something like this:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON example you have provided looks malformed.  Refer to [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for more details

Comment: Yep, my mistake when typing the sample. Now is corrected.

Comment: @Wolfchamane if it helped, why do not you accept the answer to show your appreciation to the helper?

Comment: @KickButtowski it seemed to be a typo in OP sample

Comment: [yes it is pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612659/java-json-recovers-only-one-item#comment41837633_26612659)